# Angular Reactive Forms fill inputs values with service data

Tags: angular

I need to fill Reactive Form inputs with data I get from service

I am getting user data from the service and I need to fill the user data in form inputs

My code:

```
user: any;

constructor(public _UsersService: UsersService) {
    _UsersService.getUser(this.qr_url).subscribe(data => {
        this.user = data;
    });
}


editUserForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    'name': new FormControl(this.user.name, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(100)]),
});
```

This code gives me error `Property 'user' is used before its initialization.`

note: I tried to console.log() the user and it has data not empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways.

**A)** you can define your form within the subscribe:

```
user: any;
editUserForm: FormGroup;

constructor(public _UsersService: UsersService) {
  _UsersService.getUser(this.qr_url).subscribe(data => {
    this.user = data;

    this.editUserForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(this.user.name, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3),
        Validators.maxLength(100),
      ]),
    });
  });
}
```

**B)** You can define the form as empty and then use patchForm to update the values from the subscription. https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-2-form-controls-patch-value-set-value#patchvalue

Comment: I used way A but the HTML input not filled with the data

Comment: because you have the username set asynchronously - you need an `*ngIf="editUserForm"` in your html. Because the form will not be ready until the api call is finished

Answer (score 1):

you can add *ngIf="user?.id" in your html